# How to use carriage return or line feed in the query string?

Tags: javascript, escaping

the customers can enter lines in a text area and this is saved in the database.

If the customer comes back to the site he can load the previously entered data.

However, the line feeds and carriage returns aren't displayed in the text area.

I can place them in the query string for example by ASCII coding them: %A or %D but java doesn't like that and throws an IllegalArgumentException.

So I do now: %5Cn and %5Cr which gives: \n and \r

How can I make javascript to display the escaped new lines as actual new lines in the text area?

The URL is something like:

http://www.abc.com?textarea=line1%5Cn%5Crline2

and I want the line1 and line2 to be on two different lines in the textarea.

Comment: It's Javascript not Java. Two different languages & environments.

Comment: Javascript throws an IllegalArgumentException on what code?

Comment: Encoding the strings "\r" and "\n" won't be useful to you here.

Comment: @Tomalak: you can edit your comments.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`%5C` is a literal backslash - so `%5Cn` means just "backslash and then the letter n". What you probably want is `%0A` and `%0D` instead of `%A` and `%D`. But you should URL-encode the entire string properly and not just encode two characters by hand. Use `encodeURIComponent()`. Also, use `POST` instead of `GET`, but not because the string is multiline but because you are storing it in the database. You shouldn't use the `GET` method for operations that are not idempotent.

Comment: %0A and %0B workes. I missed out on the two characters for the encoding. Thanks.