# Query String with escape characters

Tags: javascript, escaping, query-string

I need to pass some values from a textbox on a certain page, as a query string, and then receive it in another page.

The thing is want to send the escape characters for new line of the textbox `(\r\n)`

```
button.onclick = function () {
    window.open('receiver.aspx?Device=' +
                          document.getElementById('myTextbox').value);
};
```

Is that possible/allowed?

Comment: This looks like JavaScript, not C#.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use carriage return or line feed in the query string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065912/how-to-use-carriage-return-or-line-feed-in-the-query-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

```
button.onclick = function () {
    window.open('receiver.aspx?Device=' +
                 encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('myTextbox').value));
};
```

It:

> Encodes a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) component by replacing each instance of certain characters by one, two, three, or four escape sequences representing the UTF-8 encoding of the character