# Line breaks are removed calling telegram api

Tags: javascript, api, telegram

I want to send a message like a draft by calling it's api for Telegram. I searched and learned that it can be done by calling

```
`https://t.me/share/url?url=${data}`
```

I did it with **`anchor`** tag as follows:

```
<a href={`https://t.me/share/url?url=${data}`}>share to telegram</a>
```

But I have problem when I want to add line break in data string.
I tried '\n' and '\r\n' but apparently it doesn't work.

Is this the right way to call telegram api?

If yes how can I separate lines of string like there is a line break between them

[image]

But I expected sth like this:

```
before
after
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the *Telegram API*. T.me links are not part of that API.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use carriage return or line feed in the query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065912/how-to-use-carriage-return-or-line-feed-in-the-query-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this `encodeURIComponent(data)`instead of data in:

```
<a href={`https://t.me/share/url?url=${encodeURIComponent(data)}`}>share to telegram</a>
```

You basically need to call that function to, well, encode the data you want to send in a URL/URI as an argument to a post or get request

You can find a lot more info in the documentation here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

As for what exactly is a line break like \n getting encoded as. They get encoded as the `'%0A'`

Just as some general information, spaces are also invalid in URIs and they get encoded as `'%20'`